# Difference between angularjs module and java package

Tags: java, angularjs

I'm Java lecturer and build AngularJS lecture for JAVA programmers.
As I can see in the documentation of w3schools:

> Modules define applications. All application controllers should belong
>   to a module.
>
> Modules make your application more readable, and keep the global
>   namespace clean.

If I understand angularJS module has the same meaning like Java package.
Is it true or I miss something?

Comment: No, they haven't the same meaning. I suggest you read the official Angular documentation rather than W3Schools.

Comment: Where it goes wrong is that you cut out the very important in-between step; introducing said Java programmers (still not an acronym) to -javascript- programming. Jumping directly to a javascript-based web framework makes you miss a whole lot of somethings.